# Setting a column to show as sorted on a EasyUI Datagrid

Tags: javascript, datagrid, jquery-easyui

I have a EasyUI datagrid , where I am loading data remotely. When the datagrid loads the data initially, It is has a  sort order.

For eg.

```
  A   |  B    |     C
  x   |  123  |  Some other text
  y   |  657  |  text text text
  z   |  842  |  text text
```

This initial data is sorted on column A, but the datagrid is not aware of this sort order.

I am creating the datagrid entirely in javascript :

```
$('#'+elementId).datagrid({
                loadMsg: 'Processing, please wait ...',
                singleSelect:true,
                pageSize:20,
                height:'550px',
                width:'100%',
                striped:true,
                fitColumns:true,
                rownumbers:true,
                onLoadSuccess:function(){
                    ....
                },
                columns:getLayout()
                loadFilter:loadFilter,
                onBeforeLoad:function(param){
                    //Add some additional params and load data from server
                },
                onBeforeSortColumn:function(sort,order){
                    ...
                },
                onSortColumn:function(sort,order){
                    ....
                }

            });
```

How do I set the sort order on a particular column through javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using 1.3.6 or later version then you can do as below

```
    onLoadSuccess:function(){
.......
........
//At last of your code
       $('#'+elementId).datagrid('sort', {          
        sortName: 'columnid',
        sortOrder: 'desc'
      });
    }
```

Comment: Wow, 2 years later; I came back to this question because I got a "Popular question badge". Looking back, this is exactly what I did. Gonna accept this answer :).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
sortName:'itemid',
sortOrder:'asc',
remoteSort:false, //optional
```

source: http://www.itqibing.com/onlines/jQuery-easyui-docs/jQuery-easyui-docs/jQuery%20EasyUI%20%20Add%20sorting%20to%20DataGrid.htm

Comment: This works, but the problem is that it sends another request to the server to fetch the sorted data(Equivalent of clicking the column header). What I need is to set a sort order on the data loaded the first time.